# Querying on both columns in one town of a table

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have in my head what should be a simple thing to do but can't seem to find the answer.

I am given a list from a client 
e.g `name timestamp`

I want to put these in a temporary table then query them in turn e.g.

```
select reading where reading_table 
where name = t.c1 row1 and timestamp =t.c2 row1
```

and then just loop round each entry in the table

I could just hard code each entry from the client file as a select but thought there should be a better way of doing it as formatting is a problem when hardcoding and there is potential no rows found for some of them.

e.g.

```
select reading where reading_table 
where name = row1 name and timestamp = row1 timestamp
select reading where reading_table 
where name = row2 name and timestamp = row2 timestamp
```

.
.
.

```
select reading where reading_table 
where name = lastrow name and timestamp = lastrow timestamp
```

If it was just one column I would just use an IN but not sure what do 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should use `JOIN` operator. But you were very close anyway:

> *If it was just one column I would just use an IN but not sure what do 2 columns.*

`IN` supports multiple columns.

```
SELECT reading 
FROM reading_table 
WHERE (name, timestamp) IN (SELECT name, timestamp FROM client);
```

Warning! This will work only if  both columns are defined as `NOT NULL`.